# Persisting values in the plugin object for a jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I'm trying to write a simple jQuery plugin that follows similar structure to the one below. The problem I'm having is that when I initialize the plugin the value plugin.myValue is set to 1 however when I try to access that value in the talk function it's undefined. Can anyone help me refine this plugin structure so when I set values on the plugin object they can be accessed in different methods.

Please keep in mind that the plugin below is not my actual use case it is just a simple example to illustrate the problem I'm having.

My actual use case would be very long because it is a jQuery carousel that I'm writing. If it will help I can provide that code however it's much longer and the below example follows the same flow. I would initialize this plugin with the following code:

$('#Div1').talk({ message: "test message" });
$('#Div1').talk('talk');

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.talk = function(method) {

    var settings = {};
    var $el = $(this);
    var plugin = this;

    var methods = {
        init: function(options){
            settings = $.extend(true, settings, this.talk.defaults, options);

            return this.each(function() {                    
                plugin.myValue = 1;                 
            });
        },
        talk: function(){                
            helpers.talk(settings.message);
        }         
    }

    var helpers = {            
        talk: function(message){                
            if (plugin.myValue == 1)
            {
                alert(message);
            }               
        }           
    }

    if (methods[method]) {
        return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
        return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    } else {
        $.error( 'Method "' +  method + '" does not exist in talk plugin!');
    }      
}

$.fn.talk.defaults = {
    message: "default message"
}    
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Do you *have* your actual use case? Otherwise we're kind of just shooting blind here...

Comment: I can provide the full use case however this follows the same flow. I would initialize this plugin by calling: $('#Div1').talk({ message: "test message" }); and then I would call the talk function by calling $('#Div1').talk('talk');

Comment: `this` and `plugin` are actually the jQuery object. Setting a value to it doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define a plugin, `this` refers already to the jquery object (not the dom element), so I think your plugin var should go en each element, like this:

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.talk = function(method) {

    var settings = {};
    var $el = this;   //Not need of $() here        

    var methods = {
        init: function(options){
            settings = $.extend(true, settings, this.talk.defaults, options);

            return this.each(function(index, item) {                    
                item.myValue = 1;                //check this 
            });
        },
        talk: function(){                
            helpers.talk.call(this, settings.message);  //talk needs scope
        }         
    }

    var helpers = {            
        talk: function(message){
            var $elems = this;                
            if ($elems[0] && $elems[0].myValue == 1) //Something like this
            {
                alert(message);
            }               
        }           
    }

    if (methods[method]) {
        return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
        return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    } else {
        $.error( 'Method "' +  method + '" does not exist in talk plugin!');
    }      
}

$.fn.talk.defaults = {
    message: "default message"
}    
})(jQuery);
```

I hope you get my idea. Don't forget that your selector might match to more than one element. You were stroring the data to the jquery object, and don't forget that *it's a different one each time you call `$("#yourDiv")`*, so your data was lost.

Note: It'd be cleaner to do `$(item).data('myValue', 1);` instead of `item.myValue = 1;` (and its proper retrieval), but it's a matter of choice

**EDIT** Option 2. This may look more similar to your code, but *will work only when your selector only matched a single element*

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.talk = function(method) {

    var settings = {};
    var $el = this;   //Not need of $() here

    var methods = {
        init: function(options){
            settings = $.extend(true, settings, this.talk.defaults, options);
            $el.data("myValue", 1);                 
        },
        talk: function(){                
            helpers.talk(settings.message);
        }         
    }

    var helpers = {            
        talk: function(message){                
            if ($el.data("myValue") == 1)
            {
                alert(message);
            }               
        }           
    }

    if (methods[method]) {
        return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
        return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    } else {
        $.error( 'Method "' +  method + '" does not exist in talk plugin!');
    }      
}

$.fn.talk.defaults = {
    message: "default message"
}    
})(jQuery);
```

Hope this helps. Cheers